# final hand of texas holdem 4 players all in. 2 players have the same exact hand

Tags: texas-hold-em

final hand, 4 players are all in.  2 of the winning
 players have the same exact hand, how are the chips distributed from the 2 losers who have to match the winning hand.

Comment: Not enough information. We need to know how much money each has in the pot, and in what order their hands are ranked.

Comment: Additionally, it's likely a dupe, as there are several other questions on dealing with split pots.

Comment: Hi Linda, please search the site for rules on how to split pots. That should answer your question,. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Evenly.

I.E. let's say everyone has 100 chips. The pot in total is 400 chips, the two winning players both receive an even amount of 200 chips.

If there is an amount that cannot be split evenly the odd chip goes to the next big blind.

A more complicated but more likely situation could be something like this:
Player A has 100 chips, Player b has 200 chips, Player C and D both have 400 chips.

Player A and B win the hand.

The main pot will be 400 (100 from each player) chips as Player A only has 100 chips, the side pot Player B wins will have an extra 300 (100 from Player B,C and D) chips in the pot. Player C and D can fight for a 3rd side pot, but that isn't important here. So in this example Player A will receive 200 chips, while Player B will receive 500 chips, because the main pot for all players is split between Player A and Player B (200 each), and Player B will win the side pot of 300 chips.

Another scenario could be something similar but Player B has the most chips. I.E. Player A has 100 chips, Player B has 400 and Player C and D both have 200 chips. In this case, Player A still wins 200 the same amount but now because Player B has more chips than C and D they will win all their extra chips. Which would leave Player A with 200 chips and Player B with 700 chips.